# PowerBuilder (PBOrca) automated builds

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

I have a working automated build process for our PowerBuilder app running every night.  The resource I used to set this up was http://dm.char.com.ua/pb/pborca.htm.  It's not clear to me whether PBOrca is an officially supported tool or who is in charge of it (is it the gentleman who runs the linked site?).  I downloaded it from that link but I believe there may be a newer version out.  Where would I get this? I have googled to no avail and have found documentation on usage at sybase.com but no actual download.

The reason I am looking for a new version is the new style controls supported in PB11.5 are not available from the automated build, yet work fine from development, so when we deploy the build it uses a sort of Windows classic theme.  I have found references to passing NEWVSTYLECONTROLS online in other people's orca scripts but it complains about the wrong number of parameters when I try it and the examples I look at have a different parameter list.

Thanks for you time.

Alan

Comment: PowerBuilder! It's like hearing from a long lost friend. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORCA used to be uploaded to [CodeXchange](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1058501), but the last version I see uploaded is 10.2. CX is in a transition, so that may explain why it's not up to date.

However, using ORCA to build these days is less like making a cake from scratch, and more like growing your own wheat to make a cake. (Take it from a cake decorator's son, they're all from mixes. ;-) ) ORCAScript is a batch-like language to do builds. See Appendix B in the User Guide that should be installed on your machine, or link to the [User Guide online](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc00844_1150/pdf/pbug.pdf). Also note that as of PB8, you can [deploy projects from the command line](http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/New_In_PowerBuilder_8/PB8_New_-_Building_and_deployi/pb8_new_-_building_and_deployi.html).

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'll try and use OrcaScript.

Comment: And FWIW, Appeon PowerBuilder allows for a build machine without the need for an additional PowerBuilder license, unlike versions prior to PB 2017.

Answer (score 3):

We have good experience with E.Crane PowerGen. It's not free but it is a solid solution for your automated build process.

http://ecrane.com/powergen-overview/

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into though the cost maybe an off putter for my boss :-|.  It's good to know that exists though.

Comment: +1 for PowerGen, we've used it here for years. Mind you years ago it was the only way of getting a consistent, repeatable build. PB doesn't have that problem these days

Comment: I also recommend PowerGen.  I used it for many years to automate our PowerBuider builds.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I used powerbuilder.
There were till some years back tools written for creating the executables by individuals. As the PB community is becoming smaller, it is most likely that these guys havent updated the utility to newer versions.

The best approach would be for you to build your own application using the API's given by Sybase. As you may already know the details are at this location.
http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pb/adt0650e/orca/@Generic__BookTextView/86

Goodluck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think PBOrca was just some guys program which meant writing your own c program to invoke Orca directly wasn't needed and hence save a bunch of time.  The site doesn't say that so when I first found it and then Sybase referring to Orca I though PB orca was an official tool.

Comment: I've emailed the developer directly to see if he can help but you may well be right in terms of not maintaining it any longer.  The prospect of writing my own tool in C doesn't particularly appeal but may have to happen.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

TRY :

build executable "easynexus32.exe" "wings.ico" "" "YYYYYYYY" newvstylecontrols

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ORCA is still a Sybase product included in PB 11.5.1
The binary that process the script can be found in places like :
c:\program files\Sybase\shared\powerbuilder\orcascr115.exe

I ended up recently with the same syntax as the one described by Philip Ross.